# How to call index.php on startup

Tags: php, html

I get my web site appears only by typing the following: [www.example.com/index.php](http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php)

when typing: [www.example.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) nothing happens.

How to call `index.php` on startup by typing my website's address.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: coz all servers redirect to index.php by default.... unless and until at webserver level it has been sent to something else

Comment: @swapnilsarwe that's not necessarily true.  Some webservers only look for index.html or index.htm by default, not index.php.

Comment: @swapnilsarwe iis is set to look at Default.asp i think by default

Comment: ok thanks for the information, limited knowledge abt windows and iis. thanks for correcting me

Comment: I’m using Xampp. Now when my index.php contains many links to javascript, Ajax, css and MySQL connection, so only part of the above links are being directed when using the shortcut typing (www.mywebsite.com), but when I type www.mywebsite.com/index.php everything works properly and all the links are being directed.

Comment: @user1315169, if it's important to your question (and the web server software IS important in this case), you should click the "edit" link under your question and add this information.

Answer (score 3):

Create a .htaccess file and put it in your server root. Add the following to the file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

Comment: That presumes OP is running Apache. Could be IIS or something else.

Comment: Providing this is for Apache it would be better to add it to the VirtualHost *if* possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the `server` section of your nginx.conf (or whatever file it includes), make sure you have the line:

```
index index.php;
```

You ARE running nginx, aren't you?  ;-)

Comment: I’m using Xampp. Now when my index.php contains many links to javascript, Ajax, css and MySQL connection, so only part of the above links are being directed when using the shortcut typing (www.mywebsite.com), but when I type www.mywebsite.com/index.php everything works properly and all links are being directed.

Comment: @user1315169: XAMPP is a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack), not a web server.  But at least that tells us you are running Apache.  You should have said so in your question, to avoid wasted answers.  Also, "mywebsite.com" is owned by a web hosting company, and is probably *not* yours.  When making example URLs, you should use the domain **example.com**, which is reserved for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

While you have not provided any technical details on your web server, I would suggest looking into [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex).

> The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for,
>   when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a /
>   at the end of the directory name. Local-url is the (%-encoded) URL of
>   a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is
>   usually the name of a file in the directory. Several URLs may be
>   given, in which case the server will return the first one that it
>   finds. If none of the resources exist and the Indexes option is set,
>   the server will generate its own listing of the directory.

Example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

A request for http://mysite.com/docs/ would return http://mysite.com/docs/index.php if it exists, or would list the directory if it did not.